# Values of formula fields using NOW() and TODAY() actually stored in the database?

Tags: formula, database

Just for the sake of argument, if I had  the following formula field:

```
MyObject__c.FormulaField__c = DAY(TODAY())
```

What is the actual value of this field stored in the database, will the value change the next day?

Answer (score 7):

The answer to this question just got more interesting as of the Spring 13 release.

I would take a moment to read this [recent blog post on large data volumes and custom indexes](http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/02/force-com-soql-best-practices-nulls-and-formula-fields.html) to get more details.

Essentially, as of Spring 13, it is possible to contact support and ask that a custom formula field be indexed, which, in that case, *something* must be stored in the database.

But this only is allowed for deterministic formulas. NOW and TODAY are called out quite explicitly as non-deterministic in nature.

So the answer is still "no". Formula field values with TODAY and NOW are not stored in the database, and will always be recalculated on record *read*. I just felt this was a great opportunity to draw attention to this new indexing feature.

Answer (score 6):

Formula fields are not stored in the database they are calculated at query time.  As a result they always have the correct value.

Comment: That's interesting; especially from an architectural perspective. I always thought, in an application, models would simply be direct mappings of database tables. I never thought models could be further "enhanced" at query time before being consumed by an application. Just out of curiosity, does this query-time calculation occur at the DB layer, or at the app layer? Is this what tools like hibernate provide?

Comment: Its part of the translation from SOQL -> SQL.  SOQL query gets parsed, formula fields get picked up on, and the formula which makes up the field is injected into the SQL query.